# How do I disable all the developer tools in my web application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I want to prevent the user of my web application from accessing my client side data in webSQL and IndexedDB. I want to disable the developer tools in Google chrome browser. The user should not be able to access developer tools by right click or f12 or ctrl+shift+j or even by clicking on the wrench>more tools>develper tools. 
I want to disable this only in my application. How can I accomplish this?
Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Using javascript, this is for sure not possible.

Comment: WebSQL and IndexedDB should only be used for non-sensitive data, knowing that any visitors with web programming knowledge will be able to view it and change it (although if they change it and it messes up the intended functionality of the app, that's their fault of course).

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do this.

The developer menu is on the client side and is provided by the user's browser.

Also the browser developer should have nothing to do with your server side database code, and if it does, you need some major restructuring.

Comment: You literally copied an answer from linked question !

Comment: YOU COPIED THIS ANSWER LOL